# Reactstrap: Row/Col classes (col-6) aren't working for a Card component

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-4, reactstrap

I have a React app and am using `Reactstrap` to style my components. I want a single `Card` to run with full width of my `Container`, so I am using the classes `col-md-6` for two different parts of the `CardBody`, but it's still stacking vertically instead of horizontally across. I want the price and "Select" button to be side-by-side with the Product Title and description. I have the bootstrap cdn in my `index.html` file and I know it's connected because I have Bootstrap classes working in other components of my app. Can anyone help me figure out how to get it to stack horizontally?

[image]

My code:

```
// component is wrapped in a <Container> in the parent component
<Row>
  <Card>
    <Col className="col-6">
      <CardBody>
        <h5>Product title</h5>
        <CardText>Some quick example text to build on the product title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</CardText>
      </CardBody>
    </Col>
    <Col className="col-6">
      <CardBody>
        <h6>Price: { cost }</h6>
        <Button color="success" size="lg" onClick={ handleSelection }>Select</Button>
      </CardBody>
    </Col>
  </Card>
</Row>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. Something about the `Card` component's classes throws things off. If you wrap the `Row` in the `Card` instead of the other way around, it will work.

```
<Card>
  <Row>
    <Col>
      <CardBody>
        <h5>Product Title</h5>
        <CardText>Text about product</CardText>
      </CardBody>
    </Col>
    <Col>
      <CardBody>
        <h6>Price: 50</h6>
        <Button>Select</Button>
      </CardBody>
    </Col>
  </Row>
</Card>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think, you forgot row styles. It should be like this =>

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm">
           One of three columns
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm">
           One of three columns
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```